# How to put TextBox1.Text inside of string?

Tags: vb.net

I have this so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    p.FileName = "java"
    p.Arguments =
    Process.Start(p)
    Close()
End Sub
```

And after p.Arguments, I need something like `"TextBox1.Text ""-jar app.jar"""` but I know that will not work because I've tried it. I need the text in TextBox1 to be inserted into the string somehow. I want it to run... `java %TEXTBOX% -jar app.jar` How do I do this?

EDIT:
I have tried String.Format Method in combination with a lot of things - it never actually allocates memory to Java, just uses the default memory; 1gb. I have tried many, many methods and it either doesn't open, or it opens without allocating memory.

Answer (score 0):

Someone have something like this .. Just Try ..

```
Dim prc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
prc.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Java/jdk/jre/bin/java.exe")
prc.StartInfo.Arguments = "  -jar " & """" & textbox1.text & """"
prc.Start()
prc.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Like in the previous answer, it can't "find the file specified."
Edit: the "other answer" appears to be deleted

Comment: I have a space. I still get file not found.

Comment: @ElijahGoforth .. Is there mentioned what file was not found ?

Comment: No, but the only file possible for it not to find is Java. If it could not find app.jar, Java would be saying so.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap the filename in quotes:

```
p.Arguments = Chr$(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr$(34) & " -jar app.jar"
```

Are you sure, though, that it's the filename in TextBox1 that can't be found?  It may need a fully qualified path to "java", and you may also need to set the WorkingDirectory() property.

Comment: Chr$(34) is not in .NET.  Chr(34) is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, so you could use that.  Regardless, I try to avoid using the old VB-only stuff when there is a .NET equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

check this script:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim qte = """"
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    p.FileName = "java"
    p.Arguments = qte & TextBox1.Text & qte & " " & "-jar app.jar" 'or change TextBox1.Text to TextBox1.Text.ToString
    Process.Start(p)
    Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format.aspx) would be my first choice.